# How might we use ThebeLab to execute a code cell which is backed by a Jupyter Notbook with an ielixir kernel

Tags: jupyter-notebook, elixir, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to embed code cells from a jupyter notebook running an ielixir kernel by using [Thebe Lab](https://github.com/executablebooks/thebe) so that I can create a series of interactive Elixir exercises on a website. To achieve this goal I took the minimal starter from the documentation and changed the `binderOptions` in the first `<script>` tag as well as the default code section in the `<pre>` tag at the end.

Here's the example code:

```
<body>

<script type="text/x-thebe-config">
    {
      requestKernel: true,
      binderOptions: {
        name: "Elixir",
        repo: "J0/binder-el",
        kernelName: "ielixir",
        path: "./.local/share/jupyter/kernels/ielixir",
      },
    }
  </script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/thebelab@latest/lib/index.js"></script>

<button id="activateButton"  style="width: 150px; height: 75px; font-size: 1.5em;">Activate</button>
<script>
var bootstrapThebe = function() {
    thebelab.bootstrap();
}

document.querySelector("#activateButton").addEventListener('click', bootstrapThebe)
</script>
<pre data-executable="true" >IO.puts("Hello world")</pre>

</body>
```

The repository [J0/binder-el](https://github.com/J0/binder-el) is a repository with a single Dockerfile containing the setup required to run an Elixir kernel as per the [ielixir repository](https://github.com/pprzetacznik/IElixir). I have tested it before hand when using `binder.org` and I am able to successfully execute `IO.puts("Hello world")` in the notebook that I created.

Unfortunately, I'm left slightly puzzled because the run button seems to execute an `ipython` kernel even though I've specified `kernelName: ielixir`. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of the error]
I'm just wondering if I'm missing something or if anyone has suggestions as to how I might modify the  existing setup to support the ielixir kernel.

I have also create a [discussion thread on the thebelabs repository](https://github.com/executablebooks/meta/discussions/180) but I figured it would be worthwhile to post the question here as the forum seems relatively inactive.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as it turns out, you need to configure two options.

1. You need to leave the data-language tag on.

```
<pre data-executable="true" data-language="ielixir">IO.puts("Hello world")</pre>
```

2. Kernel options and Binder options need to be specified seperately

```
<script type="text/x-thebe-config">
    {
      requestKernel: true,
      binderOptions: {
        repo: "J0/binder-el",

      },
      kernelOptions: {
        name: "Elixir",
        kernelName: "ielixir",

      }
    }
  </script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/thebelab@latest/lib/index.js"></script>
```

Take great note that `kernelName` and not `name` should be `ielixir`. After that it should work! Will write a blog post summarizing the procedure and update this thread shortly.